# mvc pass Model object as variable to reduntant function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, function, razor, model, controller

Have a MVC5 c# Entity Framework Project.
Have a MVC project and trying to reduce my functions and have several that are basically the same. The functions  are updating the same 3 fields: operator, date and function performed on the  table. Each function references  different table names and field names.   Is there a way to pass the Model table  and field names into the function so I don't have to have one for each table in the Model?

These are my functions:

```
  internal void TrackAggrTest(mts_aggrtest mts_aggrtest, string struser, string action)
    {
        // Tract User Action AggrSpec 
        mts_aggrtest.F_OPRID = struser.ToString().Substring(struser.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1).ToUpper();
        mts_aggrtest.F_DATENT = DateTime.Today;
        mts_aggrtest.F_FUNCT = action.ToString();

        return;
    }



    internal void TrackBoltTest(mts_bolttest mts_bolttest, string struser, string action)
    {
        // Tract User Action mts_meshtest 
        mts_bolttest.T_OPRID = struser.ToString().Substring(struser.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1).ToUpper();
        mts_bolttest.T_DATENT = DateTime.Today;
        mts_bolttest.T_FUNCT = action.ToString();

        return;
     }


    internal void TrackBoltSpec(mts_boltspec mts_boltspec, string struser, string action)
    {
        // Tract User Action mts_meshtest 
        mts_boltspec.TS_OPRID = struser.ToString().Substring(struser.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1).ToUpper();
        mts_boltspec.TS_DATENT = DateTime.Today;
        mts_boltspec.TS_FUNCT = action.ToString();

        return;
    }
```

These functions are called in the Controllers  in the Edit/Create Actions.

In the  MTS_aggrspecController in the Create action I have:

```
     var struser = (Session["myUser"]).ToString();
     b.TrackAggrSpec(mts_aggrspec, struser, "A");
```

In the EDIT action:

```
     var struser = (Session["myUser"]).ToString(); 
     b.TrackAggrSpec(mts_aggrspec, struser, "U");
```

In the  MTS_aggrtestController the function is called :

```
     var struser = (Session["myUser"]).ToString(); 
     b.TrackAggrTest(mts_aggrtest, struser, "U");
```

This just seems so redundant and know there MUST be a better way I just don't know how.

Have  looked at other post but can't find one that seems to suit this problem.  Any help is appreciated or if can point me in right direction.

Comment: What language and framework are you using?

Comment: The Project is  a MVC5 C# Entity Framework Project. I do see where I could pass the model in to the function  and think that would work - just don't see how to handle the different field names. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should really consider lower-case parameters (Action should be action).

Comment: Erik Philips I didn't even notice that that's for the tip.

Comment: Can you pass part of the field name as a parameter? and use that in the assignment?  Maybe I can just pass the fields instead of the model.

Comment: Thank you for you effort and knowledge it is appreciated! I have the 29 Track functions finished in my project so I will trudge onto another task - this just seems SO redundant to repeat for each Model. Thank you again.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you don't need to call `ToString()` for strings.

```
    mts_boltspec.TS_OPRID = struser
      .ToString()
      .Substring(struser.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1)
      .ToUpper();
    mts_boltspec.TS_FUNCT = Action.ToString();
```

Should just be

```
    mts_boltspec.TS_OPRID = struser
      .Substring(struser.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1)
      .ToUpper();
    mts_boltspec.TS_FUNCT = Action;
```

Secondly, Microsoft guidelines suggest lowercase parameters

```
internal void TrackAggrTest(mts_aggrtest mts_aggrtest, string struser, string Action)
```

should be

```
internal void TrackAggrTest(mts_aggrtest mts_aggrtest, string struser, string action)
```

Lastly, you don't need an empty return statement.

```
internal void TrackAggrTest(mts_aggrtest mts_aggrtest, string struser, string action)
{
    mts_boltspec.TS_OPRID = struser
      .Substring(struser.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1)
      .ToUpper();
    mts_boltspec.TS_DATENT = DateTime.Today;
    mts_boltspec.TS_FUNCT;
}
```

With the basics out of the way, you can combine all these methods into one using [generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/) and [Action (delegate)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action?view=netframework-4.7.2).  To make readable, I would also create an extension method.

```
internal static class TrackAggrTestExtensions
{
  public static void TrackAggrTest<TBoltSpec>(this TBoltSpec instance,
    string struser,
    string funct,
    Action<TBoltSpec, string> assignOprId,
    Action<TBoltSpec, DateTime> assignDateNT,
    Action<TBoltSpec, string> assignFunct) 
  {
    var oprid = struser
      .Substring(struser.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1)
      .ToUpper();
    var datent = DateTime.Today;

    assignOprId(instance, oprid);
    assignDateNT(instance, datent);
    assignFunct(instance, funct);
  }
}
```

Now your calls looks like:

```
myAggrTest.TrackAggrTest(struser, 
  action, 
  (i, id) => i.F_OPRID = id,
  (i, dt) => i.F_DATENT = dt,
  (i, f) => i.F_FUNCT = f);

myBoltTest.TrackAggrTest(struser, 
  action, 
  (i, id) => i.T_OPRID = id,
  (i, dt) => i.T_DATENT = dt,
  (i, f) => i.T_FUNCT = f);

myBoltSpec.TrackAggrTest(struser, 
  action, 
  (i, id) => i.TS_OPRID = id,
  (i, dt) => i.TS_DATENT = dt,
  (i, f) => i.TS_FUNCT = f);
```

Not really sure that's any better however.